# How to select the largest values (element by element) cross vectors and give a name for each point based on its vector's name in R

Tags: r

### My problem in short:

I have 3 different vectors. Each contains `n` values. I need to compare the value of each element across these vectors. For example, compare the first values among all the vector. Then, select the largest values among them. After that, I need to name this element based on its vector's name. For example if the chosen value come from the first vector (say A), then names it as A and so on for other values.

### What I have tried is:

I have a data set (in R base) called `iris`. It contains `3` classes.
I compute the posterior for each element based on the density of each class. The values are stored in `post.Setosa`, `post.Versicolor`, and `post.Virginica`.

### What I want to get:

I would like to compare, element by element, the `3` vectors. Then name the selected element as the name of its vector. For example, here is the first values of each class:

```
> post.Setosa[[1]]

    [1] 1.339348
    > post.Virginica[[1]]
    [1] 9.292436e-25
    > post.Versicolor[[1]]
    [1] 4.244811e-17
```

The largest value is the one came from `post.Setosa`. Then, I need to names this point as `Setosa` and then do the same process for all the other point.

### What I expected to have is a data frame that return me a name for each point. For example,

```
1 Setosa

2 Setosa

3 Virginica 

4 Setosa
```

and so so.

### here is my code

```
data(iris)
dim(iris)[[1]]
##split the data based on its class
NewData <- split(iris, iris$Species)
## divide the data based on their class
NewDatSetosa <- NewData$setosa[,1:4]
NewDatVersicolor <- NewData$versicolor[,1:4]
NewDatVirginica <- NewData$virginica[,1:4]

##combined the data
NewDataCombine <- iris[,1:4]
##divide the data into train and test datasets
set.seed(1234)
datadivision <- sample(2, nrow(iris), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.67, 0.33))
iris.training <- iris[datadivision==1, 1:4]
iris.test <- iris[datadivision==2, 1:4]
##Compute the posterior for each class

posterior <- function(data,prior,newDat){
  post <- list()
  den <- lapply(1:4, function(i) dnorm(data[[i]], mean(newDat[[i]]), sd(newDat[[i]])))
     post <- prior*den[[1]]*den[[2]]*den[[3]]*den[[4]]
  return(post)
}
post.Setosa <- posterior(iris.training, prior=0.3, NewDatSetosa)
post.Versicolor <- posterior(iris.training, prior=0.3, NewDatVersicolor)
post.Virginica <- posterior(iris.training, prior=0.3, NewDatVirginica)
```

Comment: Like so: `tmp <- as.data.frame(mget(ls(pattern = "^post\\."))); sub("^post\\.", "", names(tmp)[max.col(tmp)])` ? Instead of creating many objects in your global env its better to work with lists that keep everything together.

Comment: @markus Thank you so much for your help. Yes, that what I need. However, could you please post it as an answer and explain to me what does `mget`, `ls` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have objects in the global environment called `post.Setosa`, `post.Versicolor` and `post.Virginica` we can get these objects into a list using `mget`. The function takes a character vector of object names as `x` arguemnt.

`ls()` and its `pattern` argument are useful because this function gives us this character vector of object names in a specified environment. So we are looking for objects with names that start with ( `^` ) "post." (note the `.` is a special character and needs to be escaped.

```
tmp <- as.data.frame(mget(ls(pattern = "^post\\.")))
head(tmp)
#  post.Setosa post.Versicolor post.Virginica
#1   2.5123805    7.490184e-18   5.407580e-25
#2   1.3393479    4.244811e-17   9.292436e-25
#3   1.0468302    2.477965e-18   7.580052e-26
#4   0.9771889    2.999585e-17   8.492393e-25
#5   0.1030143    2.799652e-15   4.475235e-22
#6   1.3135765    3.049651e-17   1.049321e-24
```

Now for each row we are looking for the maximum and `max.col` does exactly that. The result is a numeric vector that we use to extract the names from `tmp`. `sub` removes the `post.` from each element.

Result

```
out <- sub("^post\\.", "", names(tmp)[max.col(tmp)])
head(out)
# [1] "Setosa" "Setosa" "Setosa" "Setosa" "Setosa" "Setosa"
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using `tidyverse`-packages. I used a `map`-function from `purrr`-package: `p` means I can give it a list of length `p` as input, `_chr` means it returns a character vector. With `pmap_chr` you can use a function to do an elementwise operation. In this case, I used `case_when` from `dplyr`-package to test which value is equal to the maximum. Last, I used `bind_cols` to make a `tibble` to show the result.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

largest <- pmap_chr(
  list(post.Setosa, post.Versicolor, post.Virginica), 
  function(x, y, z){
    max <- max(max(x, y), z)
    case_when(
      x == max ~ "Setosa",
      y == max ~ "Versicolor",
      z == max ~ "Virginica"
    )
  }
)

result <- bind_cols(Setosa = post.Setosa, Versicolor = post.Versicolor, Virginica = post.Virginica, largest = largest)
```

Comment: If OP had `20` objects that they need to compare this approach wouldn't help much IMHO. Also check out `pmax` and `do.call` to find the elementwise maximum of list elements, i.e. `do.call(pmax, list(post.Setosa, post.Versicolor, post.Virginica))`